# Custom CLI similar to "npm install" that will install libs in folder other than "node_modules"

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, npm-install

I understand that "npm install" in NodeJS will actually install libraries into a folder called "node_modules".

I am actually wanting to achieve something similar but to use my own CLI instead (eg using commands like "myproject install" instead of "npm install") and then the libraries (proprietary ES6 source codes from my company's Enterprise Git Repo) will be installed into a specific folder (eg "myown_modules" rather than "node_modules").

Question is, how do I achieve that, assuming that I want dependencies checking as well on the libraries that are going to be installed? Also, how do we control versions using own CLI?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasoning for wanting a different folder? `node_modules` is part of Node itself, `npm` is just following conventions that Node itself establishes, so if you install things in a totally separate folder, you'll have to hardcode paths like `require("./myown_modules/git-repo-thing")` instead of `require("git-repo-thing")`. You might be better off using scoped packages like `node_modules/@your_company/thing` to you can do `require("@your_company/thing")`.

Comment: Reason behind is that we want to use our own libraries which will be referenced at "fixed" locations or paths. We are trying to automate things as much as possible which may be helpful for new developers who join. For instance, new developers (with their new NodeJS environment set up) can just call our CLI to install the basic scaffold-ed structure with the relevant "base" libraries installed. So when he/she codes, he can just reference from those specific paths instead. And of course, by putting in specific folders make reading easier than to lookup from node_modules folder.

Comment: And partly also because of the "best practices" which we leverage on, where we want proper segregation of external open sourced libraries (which will be installed in default node_modules folder) and internal proprietary libraries (installed in specific folders other than node_modules).

Comment: Won't it be a huge pain to import from your own custom directory though, since you've have to use a relative path rather than relying on Node to automatically resolve dependencies? Placing your code in an `@scope` would also put all your proprietary libs in one place while still relying on standard `node_modules`. I understand the decide the help new devs, but it seems like departing from community standards does the opposite of that.

Comment: Yes, it would be relative path referencing, but the paths won't be that long. As long as int and ext libs aren't mixed up. Actually, the main aim is to create a basic scaffold by running simple command line. I guess that's the basic objective that we want to achieve...

Comment: Also, if there is a way to make the referencing path shorter would be great too ie making NodeJS project by default to find libs from "node_modules" and also a predefined folder other than "node_modules".

Answer (score 0):

Use this repo and modify it to do what you want.

You need to change the install folder and change the process with the name you want.

NPM repo : https://github.com/npm/npm

OR :

Create a bash script who will do `npm install xxxx` when you use `myscript xxxx`, so you can't change the `node_modules` with this.